# CSS footer fixed position based on minimum height

Tags: html, css

I've looked on here and on various tutorial but can't the effect I need.

So if the page content is less high than 600px I want the footer fixed below a container that is that height.

But if the content increases the container height to beyond 600px then the footer should be pushed down the page by the container.

I've tried using min-height to avail, my html look like this

```
<body>
<div id="shell">
<div id="container">
Content
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I won't bother posting the CSS as it just doesn't come close.

Comment: uhh show the css its the core of your problem.

Comment: you have to use JS for this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by CSS Trick,

**/* CSS Code */**

```
body, html{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}

.wrapper{
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.container{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-bottom:100px;
}

.header{
    height:100px;
    background-color:#066;
}

.footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#006;
    width:100%;
}
```

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="header">
            Header
        </div>

        <div class="body">

        </div>


    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is my [Fiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/8AuAn/)

Comment: The Body height needs to have a fixed min height this goes to any height

Answer (score 0):

I know you tried `min-height` but why is this not suitable?

```
#container
{
    background:#08e;
    min-height:600px;  
}


#footer
{
    background:#ddd;
}
```