# Fix footer to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, footer

Although most pages on my site have enough content to push the footer to the bottom of the page for most people. I would like to know it's always fixed to the bottom regardless of screen size from now on anyway.

I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: `0x;` `position:absolute:` etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer out of its container to fix to the bottom using some of those examples right there.

Included is the HTML and CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside of a `<section id="footer">` `div` anyway.

I removed my attempts at getting it to stick so people can have a look at it right now and see what the current code is to amend.

Live URL - http://www.mangdevelopment.co.uk/nakedradish

(It's a resturant website. Don't worry about the word 'naked').

HTML

```
<section id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span1">
        <div id="small-logo">
          <img src="img/small-logo.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span2">
        <div class="footer-list">
          <h6>OUR BOXES</h6>
          <ul>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Classic Box</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Vegetarian Box</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Family Box</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Dinner Party Box</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Gift Box</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span2">
        <div class="footer-list">
          <h6>OUR RECIPES</h6>
          <ul>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Last Weeks Feature</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Next Weeks Feature</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span2">
        <div class="footer-list">
          <h6>ABOUT US</h6>
          <ul>
            <a href="#">
              <li>The Food</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>How We Sourcex</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Sustainability</li>
            </a>
            <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Contact Us</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span5">
        <div id="twitter">
          <img src="img/twitter-logo.png" alt="" title="" height="50" width="50" class="twitter-logo" />
          <div class="tweet-bg">
            <div class="tweets">
              <p>@chefallanp that's just not on really</p>
            </div>
            <div id="follow-btn">
              <img src="img/follow-us.jpg" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="checkout-options">
          <h6>SECURE CHECKOUT</h6>
          <ul>
            <li><img src="img/solo-logo.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/switch-logo.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/maestro-logo.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/visa-logo.png" /></li>
            <a href="#">
              <li><img src="img/facebook-logo.png" /></li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li><img src="img/twitter-logo-flat.png" /></li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="copyright-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="copyright-content">
        <div class="span4">
          <p>The Naked Radish Limited. 2013 All rights reserved.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="span4 offset4">
          <div class="copyright-list">
            <ul>
              <a href="terms.html">
                <li>Terms &amp; Conditions</li>
              </a>
              <a href="privacy.html">
                <li> - Privacy Policy</li>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <li> - Cookie Policy</li>
              </a>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You can use a **sticky footer** approach. google it and you'll find code. I use the **Compass Sticky Footer**. Here's the [example](http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/layout/sticky-footer/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS footer fixed position based on minimum height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256883/css-footer-fixed-position-based-on-minimum-height)

Comment: @SharavnanKv that domain is dead

Comment: @ Benoit Blanchon the accepted answer to the question you linked is very terribly explained and uses horrible inline styles. This question now has better answers. Consider deleting your obsolete comment.

Answer (score 122):

For your `footer`:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

For your `body`:

```
body {
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

```css
#footer {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

div {
  margin: 20px 20px;
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Although most pages on my site have enough content to push the footer to the bottom of the page for most people. I would like to know it's always fixed to the bottom regardless of screen size from now on anyway. I've tried a number of ways such as bottom:
  0x; position:absolute: etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer out of it's container to fix to the bottom using some of those examples right there. Included is the HTML and CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright
  bar). They're both inside of a div anyway. I removed my attempts at getting it to stick so people can have a look at it right now and see what the current code is to amend. Although most pages on my site have enough content to push the footer to the
  bottom of the page for most people. I would like to know it's always fixed to the bottom regardless of screen size from now on anyway. I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: 0x; position:absolute: etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally
  pushes the footer out of it's container to fix to the bottom using some of those examples right there. Included is the HTML and CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside of a div anyway. I removed my attempts
  at getting it to stick so people can have a look at it right now and see what the current code is to amend. Although most pages on my site have enough content to push the footer to the bottom of the page for most people. I would like to know it's always
  fixed to the bottom regardless of screen size from now on anyway. I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: 0x; position:absolute: etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer out of it's container to fix to the bottom using
  some of those examples right there. Included is the HTML and CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside of a div anyway. I removed my attempts at getting it to stick so people can have a look at it right now and
  see what the current code is to amend. Although most pages on my site have enough content to push the footer to the bottom of the page for most people. I would like to know it's always fixed to the bottom regardless of screen size from now on anyway.
  I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: 0x; position:absolute: etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer out of it's container to fix to the bottom using some of those examples right there. Included is the HTML and CSS for
  the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside of a div anyway. I removed my attempts at getting it to stick so people can have a look at it right now and see what the current code is to amend. Although most pages on my site
  have enough content to push the footer to the bottom of the page for most people. I would like to know it's always fixed to the bottom regardless of screen size from now on anyway. I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: 0x; position:absolute: etc.
  Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer out of it's container to fix to the bottom using some of those examples right there. Included is the HTML and CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside
  of a div anyway. I removed my attempts at getting it to stick so people can have a look at it right now and see what the current code is to amend. Although most pages on my site have enough content to push the footer to the bottom of the page for most
  people. I would like to know it's always fixed to the bottom regardless of screen size from now on anyway. I've tried a number of ways such as bottom: 0x; position:absolute: etc. Never seems to work very well, occasionally pushes the footer out of it's
  container to fix to the bottom using some of those examples right there. Included is the HTML and CSS for the two parts of the footer (footer & copyright bar). They're both inside of a div anyway. I removed my attempts at getting it to stick so people
  can have a look at it right now and see what the current code is to amend.
</div>
<div id="footer">
  This is footer
</div>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/girishgowdayt/RUDWS/)

Comment: Was just given this as an answer too. Thanks but didn't mean for it to float with the user. Not on top of the content.

Comment: it will stick to footer irrespective of your content height.. your content will not be hidden as i have given margin-bottom to body..

Answer (score 65):

We can use **FlexBox** for Sticky **Footer** and **Header** without using POSITIONS in CSS.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: #037cf5;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: #134c7d;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>HEADER</header>
  <main class="content">

  </main>
  <footer>FOOTER</footer>
</div>
```

**DEMO -** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/balatamizh/av4bnacp/)

**Note** : Check browser supports for FlexBox.
[caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: works flawlessly! this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: What is the benefit of not using position?

Comment: @ftw not setting body bottom margins based on footer height

Comment: @saran3h this one and accepted answer produce different results. Accepted answer: footer is always visible, even if content is greater than screen size. This answer: footer is pushed to the bottom of screen/content, so if content is greater than screen size, you will need to scroll to see it. So everything depends on requirements.

Comment: PERFECT. Just one more thing: if anybody else is wondering where the vertical scrollbar in the fiddle example comes from, just set `margin: 0` on the body element. Then the scrollbar will only show up once there is enough content to push the footer out of view.

Answer (score 12):

Like this add `position:fixed;` and `bottom:0;` below the selector `#footer`:

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vHNyb/)**

**CSS**

```
#footer {
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry I need it to not cover the content. I've just added what you suggested which looks great but yeah starts onto of the content.

Comment: @mcvities i think footer fixed not suitable for your site if you want to fixed so top panel fixed. i think this is look good.

Comment: @falguni I think you have a typo where `px` is missing from `bottom`.  So it should be `bottom:0px` not `bottom:0`.

Answer (score 6):

Set

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Wrap the entire content before the footer in a div.

```css
.wrapper {
    height:auto !important;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

You can adjust min-height as you like based on how much of the footer you want to show in the bottom of the browser window. If set it to 90%, 10% of the footer will show before scrolling.

Answer (score 5):

CSS

```
html {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    min-height:100%; position:relative;
}
.footer {
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
    height: 115px;
    position:absolute; bottom:0px;
}
.footer-ghost { height:115px; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="header">...</div>
<div class="content">...</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
<div class="footer-ghost"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

This code working for me :

```
footer{
    background-color: #333;
    color: #EEE;
    padding: 20px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Important thing you should added `bottom:0;` and `position: fixed;`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple CSS solution that'll work:

```
#fix-footer{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #1abc9c;
}
```

Comment: The question was about fixing footer to the bottom of page, `position: fixed` fixes an element to viewport rather than page.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the sticky footer solution a bit painful on responsive sites, given that the height of your nav and footer can differ depending on the device. If you only care about working on modern browsers, you can accomplish your goal using a bit of Javascript.

If this is your HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

Then use this JQuery on every page:

```
$(function(){

  /* Sets the minimum height of the wrapper div to ensure the footer reaches the bottom */
  function setWrapperMinHeight() {
    $('.wrapper').css('minHeight', window.innerHeight - $('.nav').height() - $('.footer').height());
  }
  /* Make sure the main div gets resized on ready */
  setWrapperMinHeight();

  /* Make sure the wrapper div gets resized whenever the screen gets resized */
  window.onresize = function() {
    setWrapperMinHeight();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your footer element won't inherently be fixed to the bottom of your viewport unless you style it that way.
So if you happen to have a page that doesn't have enough content to push it all the way down it'll end up somewhere in the middle of the viewport; looking very awkward and not sure what to do with itself, like my first day of high school.

Positioning the element by declaring the `fixed` rule is great if you always want your footer visible regardless of initial page height - but then remember to set a bottom margin so that it doesn't overlay the last bit of content on that page. This becomes tricky if your footer has a dynamic height; which is often the case with responsive sites since it's in the nature of elements to stack.

You'll find a similar problem with `absolute` positioning. And although it does take the element in question out of the natural flow of the document, it still won't fix it to the bottom of the screen should you find yourself with a page that has little to no content to flesh it out.

**Consider achieving this by:**

1. Declaring a height value for the `<body>` & `<html>` tags
2. Declaring a `minimum-height` value to the nested wrapper element, usually the element which wraps all your descendant elements contained within the body structure (this wouldn't include your `footer` element)

[Code Pen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWwqqB)

```js
$("#addBodyContent").on("click", function() {
  $("<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>").appendTo(".flex-col:first-of-type");
});

$("#resetBodyContent").on("click", function() {
  $(".flex-col p").remove();
});

$("#addFooterContent").on("click", function() {
  $("<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>").appendTo("footer");
});

$("#resetFooterContent").on("click", function() {
  $("footer p").remove();
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 91%;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
}

footer {
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

.flex-col {
    flex: 1 1;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
}

.flex-btn-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.btn {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: .7s;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    min-width: 200px;
}

.btn:hover {
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dark {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.light {
    background: white;
    border: 3px solid white;
}

.light:hover {
    color: white;
}

.dark:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex-btn-wrapper">
        <button id="addBodyContent" class="dark btn">Add Content</button>
        <button id="resetBodyContent" class="dark btn">Reset Content</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex">
    <div class="flex-col">
      lorem ipsum dolor...
    </div>
    <div class="flex-col">
      lorem ipsum dolor...
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<footer>
    <div class="flex-btn-wrapper">
        <button id="addFooterContent" class="light btn">Add Content</button>
        <button id="resetFooterContent" class="light btn">Reset Content</button>
    </div>
    lorem ipsum dolor...
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Footer be positioned at the bottom of the page, but not **fixed**.

**CSS**

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;  
  padding: 0;
}
#header {
  background: #595959;
  height: 90px;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #595959;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>        
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="content"></div>
      <div id="footer"></div>     
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Grid Layout**. It is newer than Flexbox, and less supported in browsers.

Check it out:

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}   

.footer {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
```

**Useful Links:**

Browser Supoort: [Can I Use - Grid Layout](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid)

Complete Guide: [Grid Laoyut Guid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100%
}

body {
  padding-bottom: 88px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 88px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A very simple example that shows how to fix the footer at the bottom in your application's layout.

```css
/* Styles go here */
html{ height: 100%;}
body{ min-height: 100%; background: #fff;}
.page-layout{ border: none; width: 100%; height: 100vh; }
.page-layout td{ vertical-align: top; }
.page-layout .header{ background: #aaa; }
.page-layout .main-content{ height: 100%; background: #f1f1f1; text-align: center; padding-top: 50px; }
.page-layout .main-content .container{ text-align: center; padding-top: 50px; }
.page-layout .footer{ background: #333; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table class="page-layout">
      <tr>
        <td class="header">
          <div>
            This is the site header.
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="main-content">
          <div>
            <h1>Fix footer always to the bottom</h1>
            <div>
              This is how you can simply fix the footer to the bottom.
            </div>
            <div>
              The footer will always stick to the bottom until the main-content doesn't grow till footer.
            </div>
            <div>
              Even if the content grows, the footer will start to move down naturally as like the normal behavior of page.
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="footer">
          <div>
            This is the site footer.
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

Using Flex and Bootstrap4 (if you don't use Bootstrap4, you can achieve the same result using the flex properties)

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column">
    <div>Header</div>
    <div>Main container</div>
    <div class="mt-auto">Footer</div>
</body>
```