# Div to fill the rest of page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fill the rest of my content, before my footer. I've found many pages here with solutions that seem logical but don't seem to work within my page. I cant change my position status of my footer to fixed or absolute.
I currently have a div with the id of "bottomfix". I tried the fixed & zerod solution but that didn't work either.

I invite you view my [biopage](http://www.overlandparkphotographer.com/about-the-photographer/), the css that I'm working on is the last sheet titled style.css.

Comment: This can not be done with CSS only. You need JS. If you don't care about the div's size and just want the footer to stick to the bottom, google "CSS sticky footer" or something similar.

Comment: **Duplicated** see the solution here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915550/fix-footer-to-bottom-of-page

Comment: @WouterFlorijn you can use the CSS3 property `calc` I believe

Comment: @zgood That would only work if you know the exact height of ALL other content on the page. Even if you do, it's bad practice to rely on exact sizes in CSS.

Comment: @WouterFlorijn You just need to know the heights of the `<header>` and `<footer>` for it to work in this case. But I do agree this only works if the header and footer have a static height. But thats what the `calc` function is for so use it if you can!

Comment: Ok my first comment was only partially true. It can be done using flexbox for some layouts. I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this, which I think would work for your layout, is using flexbox. I actually did this for one of my own projects [(example)](http://cycleswap.nl/about). This is the best solution, since your footer and other content can have dynamic height.

General HTML structure:

```
<body>
  <main>
    Header and page content go here...
  </main>
  <footer>
    Footer...
  </footer>
</body>
```

It's important to include many different prefixes and fallbacks to make it work in all browsers (I tested it in multiple versions of Chrome, FF, IE and Safari).

CSS:

```
body {
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  box-orient: vertical;
}

main {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -moz-box-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 32px; // Whatever space you want between content and footer.
  -webkit-box-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -moz-box-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

If you want to control the size of your `.bottomfix` div, you can add more flexboxes into the `main` element.

Comment: I had to add the stuff to `#page` But this one finally fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Add to your `#footer` class `position: fixed;`
then add position `bottom: 0px;` and it will be at the bottom

```
#footer {
    border-width: 5px;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 6px 0 7px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

if you want footer to bi fixed to the bottom of the page only if your page doesn't have enough content to fill in page then add this script before `<body>` closing tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(jQuery('header:first').height()+
   jQuery('main:first').height()+ jQuery('footer:first').height() >  jQuery(window).height()){ 
   $('#footer').css({position: 'fixed', bottom: '0px'});
}
</script>
```

and this scrip will on load check if your page needs fixed footer :)

or you can add it in

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //code

});
```

Comment: This is not an option for my overall design. If you visit my homepage you will see why.

Comment: so you don't need it at the bottom if there is content that can cover whole page?, only if there is empty space?

Comment: @newby JP: I don't see why this or an absolute with bottom: 0; won't work? While this isn't pretty, since you have so many nested elements, set a min height of 100% on your html and body.  You can then use absolute with a bottom:0.

Comment: yes it does "work" but the whole point of the design is that the landing page, is a clean UN-obstructed image.

Comment: @Senad that last addition looks great! i'm to add that script before which closing tag?

Comment: added the script just above the `</body>` and it doesnt seem to do its job :( it seems like just the right fix too

Comment: then use solution number 2 it should do the job, it's hard like this to test it, but I think it will work.

Comment: I think i'm a little un familiar with your technique on how to use that style of code. From what i understand, I would place `$(document).ready(function(){

  if(jQuery('header:first').height()+
   jQuery('main:first').height()+ jQuery('footer:first').height() >  jQuery(window).height()){ 
   $('#footer').css({position: 'fixed', bottom: '0px'});
}

});`
before the `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the the CSS3 `calc` function. Like this:

```
main{
    min-height: 100%; /*fallback if browser doesn't support calc*/
    min-height: ~"calc(100% - 330px)"; /*330px comes from 270px <header> plus 60px <footer>*/
}
```

You would just have to replace the `<header>` and `<footer>` height value calculation to yours.

Also make sure you have something like this:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: did you add the `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: in your case you may also need to add `#page{ height: 100%; }`

Comment: ok the `#page` seemed to do the trick, but a bit too well. now i cant even get to my footer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: #222;
  color: #7B7B7B;
  font-size: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

This worked for me I set the position to absolute and set `bottom:0;` to force the div to the bottom of the browser

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. 66px is footer + header height

```
html, body, #page, #bottomfix, main > div {
    height: 100%;
}

main {
    height: calc(100% - 66px);
}
```

[image: example]

Comment: @zgood I tried your example, but for me min-height does not work

Comment: Thats odd, I'm using that code in couple live projects and it seems to be working. Oh well, the point is using `calc` which prevents the need for any extra javascript you need to maintain. Good solution ;)

Comment: works great on the bio page, but it strips out my content on my home page

Comment: you want in case if is more content, the footer to go down? you can't always fit all in one page, and have a "sticky" footer without scrollbar )

Comment: i dont fully understand your question

Comment: you want that footer always to be visible, doesn't matter how much content is in page? if yes, the solution is to make footer fixed.