# Google Editor Addon Verification says "broken links on homepage": what does Google wants me to do?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, verification, add-on

I've submitted an addon for verification and the Google team are telling me that the links and buttons on [my homepage](https://ofdiceandmagic.com/dms.html) are inaccessible, when they clearly aren't.

This is what they say:

> "We’ve noticed that the links and buttons on the submitted homepage are inaccessible and/or broken"

The links and buttons do in fact work and I cannot for the life of me figure out what they want me to change.

Here's the screenshot they provided as evidence:

[image: Here's the screenshot they provided as evidence]

Comment: To see the problem, click the browser's **zoom** button. At 125% with large text, my system overlaps the **buy me a coffee** button with the contents menu number 10 and 11 items. See @Ruben's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I opened your add-on homepage the bottom sidebar buttons overlaps the above sidebar links. Inspecting the buttons I see that they are children of `<footer>`. Here are some questions about similar problems:

- [CSS to make HTML page footer stay at bottom of the page with a minimum height, but not overlap the page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/643879/1595451)
- [HTML footer overlapping with content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42178542/1595451)

Review your homepage desing using different screen sizes and web browsers. At least try the major modern web-browsers: Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari.