# Footer overlaps other elements

Tags: css

I am trying to fix this footer.  If i remove `positon` it works fine but some other pages still have a problem.  I need this footer at the bottom of every page...

```
  footer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 16px;
   background:white;
}

<footer>
  <div class="container text-center"> <span>Copyright &copy; 2017 LeagueOn. all rights reserved </span> </div>
</footer>
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fix footer to bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915550/fix-footer-to-bottom-of-page)

Comment: i dont want it position fixed i want footer at the end of page

Comment: `position: relative;`?

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: It is an indication that it's parent element:height is not fullscreen, show more CSS and HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid `position: absolute` where you don't really need it.

You can achieve this via flexbox. Your `footer` should be direct child of body:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;  /* min-height: 100vh will also work everywhere except IE */
}

footer {
  /* move footer to the bottom */
  margin-top: auto;
}

/* This styles are just for demo */
body {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

footer {
  background-color: lime;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>Copyright &copy; 2017 LeagueOn. all rights reserved</footer>
```

This will work even in case of long page:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;  /* min-height: 100vh will also work everywhere except IE */
}

footer {
  /* move footer to the bottom */
  margin-top: auto;
}

/* This styles are just for demo */
body {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

footer {
  background-color: lime;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sodales molestie orci vitae facilisis. Duis non urna eget felis blandit facilisis vel sit amet purus. Donec finibus ex eget ultrices ultricies. Sed porttitor lobortis mi dignissim lacinia. Phasellus eget iaculis mauris, quis placerat augue. Quisque luctus condimentum neque, sed feugiat ipsum sagittis at. Mauris ut commodo eros.

Sed vel faucibus lacus, efficitur dapibus lectus. Sed consectetur luctus odio. Sed tempus aliquet enim, ac ullamcorper augue tincidunt at. Pellentesque vehicula iaculis elit eleifend viverra. Etiam scelerisque maximus felis. Aenean mollis nisl non eros faucibus mattis. Phasellus dictum venenatis ex vel ultricies.

Suspendisse auctor, nunc at ullamcorper hendrerit, dui enim laoreet nisl, id ullamcorper elit ex in lorem. Ut malesuada ipsum et euismod fermentum. Etiam euismod feugiat lacus eget luctus. Sed tempor vestibulum lectus. Suspendisse tincidunt ut massa ac interdum. Pellentesque mattis sapien in augue imperdiet, vel imperdiet massa convallis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vestibulum nec consectetur nunc.

Mauris vel sodales ex. Aenean at lectus non libero sagittis aliquam nec eget nisi. Proin massa tortor, iaculis in ante ut, hendrerit sodales sem. Aenean blandit vestibulum dolor et viverra. Mauris non nunc eget odio vulputate viverra. Morbi sagittis nisl at risus convallis vestibulum. Aenean pellentesque sit amet nibh id lobortis.

Ut consequat ligula risus, sit amet congue dolor consequat maximus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur ultrices tellus at placerat hendrerit. Fusce ullamcorper ante id urna scelerisque, eget interdum libero feugiat. Sed consectetur eget metus et euismod. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas malesuada interdum mauris, tempor porttitor odio porttitor eu. Vestibulum sollicitudin justo velit, nec porttitor risus luctus non. Fusce tempor dapibus magna a luctus. Donec ex turpis, venenatis vulputate lacus in, pharetra auctor nisi. Pellentesque dictum elit ut mollis vehicula. Donec vulputate suscipit felis vitae accumsan. Ut fermentum aliquam ipsum sit amet condimentum. Phasellus sollicitudin ligula elit, in efficitur leo dignissim a. Quisque dignissim dolor malesuada interdum interdum.

Nulla congue nibh erat, et tincidunt nulla maximus id. Duis placerat suscipit ex. Integer ut tortor sapien. Vestibulum dapibus sed ex at pharetra. Aliquam blandit facilisis erat. Proin imperdiet cursus arcu, non congue neque tempor nec. Maecenas ut nibh semper, dictum velit sit amet, vehicula nisl. Nullam ac tempor libero. Donec elit lorem, luctus et maximus in, iaculis sed neque. Duis vehicula lacus vitae eros congue, at molestie nisi eleifend. Nulla erat diam, dapibus eu consectetur et, rutrum non quam. Duis imperdiet laoreet elit ac varius. Nulla ultricies pellentesque libero, eget tincidunt tortor elementum quis.

Morbi vitae pharetra ante. Aenean maximus rutrum nunc, eget tempor nunc. Aenean nisi erat, egestas a rhoncus ut, tempus non nisl. Donec venenatis aliquam pulvinar. Sed in tortor neque. Fusce sollicitudin arcu vitae justo faucibus, sit amet sodales neque suscipit. Aliquam in sollicitudin diam. Donec a eros magna. Quisque vel posuere ipsum, quis vehicula odio. Morbi non dolor velit. Vivamus varius velit purus, bibendum volutpat magna eleifend ut. Quisque imperdiet pharetra nunc, id efficitur eros interdum sit amet. Sed commodo maximus risus et iaculis.

Fusce facilisis hendrerit leo. Donec a justo vel velit pellentesque congue et convallis sem. Nullam et urna justo. Donec aliquet mi ac turpis lacinia, in faucibus nunc tempor. Mauris at magna vitae ex volutpat blandit. Integer sed faucibus odio, in congue turpis. Vivamus pellentesque condimentum sagittis. Aliquam fermentum consequat massa non imperdiet.

Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris pellentesque interdum arcu, at tempor tortor tincidunt sed. Aliquam quis odio rhoncus, pharetra ligula vitae, tempus ante. Aenean ultrices ultrices purus eu interdum. Nullam malesuada dui sit amet enim feugiat dignissim. Vestibulum purus orci, fermentum vitae augue ac, semper scelerisque lectus. Etiam congue erat nec eleifend dapibus. Vestibulum vel mattis lacus. Proin urna nunc, sollicitudin quis volutpat varius, posuere vitae elit. Mauris felis ex, elementum et venenatis at, sagittis at quam. Donec nec pulvinar metus. Morbi sit amet tortor tortor.

Sed cursus fermentum nibh, ac fringilla ante dignissim non. Morbi in hendrerit lacus. Nam pulvinar ultricies dolor vitae ultrices. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent at neque sapien. Nam nisi velit, porta nec ultricies venenatis, semper sit amet mauris. Praesent sagittis ullamcorper lorem, imperdiet eleifend nisl vehicula quis. Cras ut vulputate metus. Ut in congue enim, vel efficitur tortor.

Integer velit erat, fringilla tincidunt porttitor gravida, pulvinar nec elit. Pellentesque ornare porttitor lorem ut congue. Pellentesque sagittis libero in est tristique feugiat. Suspendisse et ex fringilla dui tincidunt iaculis. Etiam a mollis enim, in scelerisque orci. Sed accumsan viverra nunc, a varius tellus molestie malesuada. Nam nec fringilla tellus, sed facilisis tortor. Nulla sed est sed orci tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi luctus imperdiet mi, eget molestie purus venenatis vel.

Integer venenatis dignissim nisi vel dignissim. Mauris vitae maximus felis, et tincidunt eros. Vivamus luctus scelerisque ligula, nec semper turpis volutpat ut. Ut vestibulum nisi vel justo iaculis, sed congue ante vulputate. Maecenas suscipit, mi at pulvinar tempus, nisl lorem molestie massa, ac vestibulum risus neque sit amet purus. Cras ultrices vulputate eros, a volutpat urna luctus ac. Curabitur viverra nunc in mauris mattis, pretium faucibus nibh convallis. Vivamus fermentum magna consectetur velit condimentum finibus. Vestibulum luctus dolor ut elit dictum, sed posuere ligula aliquam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt nisi tellus, nec iaculis tellus feugiat nec. Vivamus sodales molestie velit, quis porta augue rhoncus ac. Sed elementum mi in est venenatis, vitae posuere risus imperdiet.

Pellentesque scelerisque id urna iaculis interdum. Nulla cursus nibh at quam pretium mattis. Quisque at elit metus. Sed pellentesque, lacus et placerat tincidunt, orci metus rutrum ante, pharetra iaculis urna ipsum ac ipsum. Ut maximus ante sit amet finibus vestibulum. Nam lacinia tellus vehicula, gravida tellus vitae, maximus lacus. Integer placerat enim et fringilla commodo.

Cras non accumsan erat, vel dapibus velit. Sed eu dolor tellus. Integer varius mauris nibh, quis pharetra magna congue non. Aliquam libero nisl, suscipit eu congue id, tristique in magna. Maecenas rutrum magna non tincidunt convallis. Aliquam aliquam, mi ut dictum rhoncus, nisl neque lobortis tortor, at mattis odio eros ut justo. Vestibulum egestas risus nec nisl placerat maximus. Nunc orci purus, egestas at rutrum id, eleifend semper erat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus diam ipsum, aliquam ut placerat ac, ultrices nec arcu. Integer eu ultrices dolor, non luctus orci. Proin sodales pulvinar dui, et sollicitudin tellus dapibus nec. Praesent quis consectetur eros, non ornare tortor.

Curabitur vitae lorem vitae est scelerisque facilisis vitae non augue. Duis erat metus, iaculis a velit et, iaculis vehicula nisl. Mauris tristique pellentesque suscipit. Maecenas a nisl dui. In lacus justo, fringilla ut tortor non, dignissim aliquet nisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam non lectus libero. Proin consequat eleifend justo. Praesent dolor enim, fringilla ut accumsan sit amet, egestas et augue. Nunc mattis dolor quis sodales tempus.

Integer sed ornare dolor. Quisque id dapibus tortor. Quisque ornare, ex quis consequat porttitor, arcu justo aliquet diam, in sollicitudin odio sem laoreet dolor. Ut elit dolor, semper vitae consectetur rutrum, finibus in felis. Nunc volutpat quam ut ligula varius volutpat. Nunc porttitor dictum libero et facilisis. Nam a libero a nisi aliquet mollis. Integer eget ipsum accumsan, interdum elit sit amet, ultrices massa. Nullam nec est id lorem dignissim aliquet nec at urna. Maecenas ante lorem, rutrum ac commodo ac, viverra quis enim. Etiam convallis sapien eu leo dignissim condimentum. Morbi ut ex eu enim fermentum varius at non turpis. Nulla sed libero pharetra, ornare mi sit amet, scelerisque odio. Mauris sit amet mi non mi ornare commodo. Proin eget lacinia erat. Nunc dictum lobortis justo sed vulputate.

Proin ullamcorper finibus nisi egestas aliquam. Sed tempor ornare massa at semper. Integer ultrices diam a libero fringilla faucibus. Proin vitae leo nec neque laoreet imperdiet. Donec mattis gravida massa ac blandit. Aliquam et accumsan urna. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam rhoncus elementum est nec iaculis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et sapien orci. Vestibulum ut venenatis velit. Sed sodales volutpat risus vel aliquam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

Sed tempus nibh tempus bibendum viverra. Maecenas sit amet magna pretium, pharetra nisl at, ullamcorper elit. Integer ipsum diam, laoreet at consectetur at, rutrum eu mi. Duis et neque mauris. Pellentesque consequat augue et tortor commodo ornare. Nulla sed dui non sem vehicula bibendum vitae nec nibh. Curabitur ut arcu lacus. Donec vel orci dolor. Nam vel nibh a turpis ultricies dapibus rhoncus sit amet lorem. Aliquam condimentum mollis aliquam. Pellentesque laoreet vitae mauris id ornare. In id malesuada nisi.

Phasellus eu aliquam magna, sed efficitur dui. Morbi sagittis tellus vitae velit lacinia, ac molestie massa accumsan. Nullam molestie odio non turpis bibendum rutrum. Donec pellentesque nunc in massa ultrices, a pulvinar ex porta. Curabitur pretium placerat eleifend. Vivamus in dolor id dolor dapibus scelerisque. Etiam pretium placerat laoreet.

Nam at varius nibh, nec ullamcorper tellus. Vivamus ut metus sit amet ligula lobortis ultrices. Vestibulum sed metus id tortor pellentesque dignissim sit amet quis tellus. Integer porta laoreet massa. Fusce tincidunt eros sed neque egestas tristique. Donec eleifend elit volutpat purus sagittis gravida ut vitae purus. Suspendisse a neque id enim euismod egestas et in arcu. Vivamus placerat nulla vel ex dapibus, nec rutrum risus imperdiet. Nam aliquet felis vel turpis varius venenatis. Curabitur a tempus velit, eget vulputate dolor. Nullam feugiat risus risus, in finibus mauris egestas eu.

Donec arcu ligula, pulvinar eu dapibus ut, viverra id ante. Integer in tempus leo, quis finibus felis. Sed sollicitudin libero quis mi vehicula, et blandit tellus porttitor. In in interdum leo. Pellentesque blandit nisi eu quam tempus, vel bibendum augue accumsan. Nam eget suscipit magna, sit amet lacinia velit. Nullam tincidunt, quam a lobortis pharetra, arcu velit pulvinar risus, quis fermentum erat lacus ut neque. Aenean ex elit, feugiat semper vestibulum sed, porttitor at massa.

Proin turpis metus, commodo porta sem non, faucibus hendrerit magna. Nulla sodales gravida quam ac aliquet. Nam posuere lobortis ultricies. Nulla ac odio venenatis, tempor lorem at, varius diam. Suspendisse malesuada lacus vel sapien malesuada, quis faucibus urna eleifend. Donec aliquam erat ut est pellentesque suscipit. Nunc diam lorem, semper et porttitor vitae, commodo eget nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec eu dapibus lorem. Aenean auctor, risus vel efficitur fringilla, neque ex elementum augue, eget aliquam arcu risus quis ligula. Sed viverra mauris tortor, ut tempus risus luctus vitae. Vestibulum tincidunt blandit tortor, eu scelerisque nisl pulvinar et. Ut placerat odio urna, at consequat risus sagittis ac. Fusce imperdiet, enim ut commodo auctor, lectus ante efficitur velit, sed ullamcorper dui purus eu nunc. Nam in mauris venenatis, pretium tortor a, accumsan metus.

Donec efficitur suscipit metus id ullamcorper. Etiam ipsum eros, luctus ut maximus non, pellentesque ut dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tempor leo eu dolor pulvinar, at rutrum nulla volutpat. Curabitur quis mollis augue. Nunc porttitor suscipit odio, laoreet facilisis mi luctus convallis. Nunc urna purus, mattis at sollicitudin eget, pharetra quis sapien. Sed porttitor, lacus sed posuere aliquam, quam odio pellentesque ante, sed volutpat est justo sit amet purus. Aenean consequat condimentum tellus, in sagittis dolor molestie quis. Aenean eget enim sem. Vivamus rutrum mi in magna rutrum, vitae euismod lorem pulvinar. Quisque viverra urna odio, eu tristique orci ultricies eu. Nam facilisis malesuada mattis. Ut tempor nibh eu sapien pellentesque facilisis. Aenean fringilla urna ut lorem viverra, quis condimentum elit iaculis.

Nullam aliquam, leo nec iaculis maximus, nisl nulla pretium leo, vitae iaculis nunc mi sit amet ante. Donec ullamcorper velit vitae dictum placerat. Nulla facilisi. Donec lobortis ut diam et pulvinar. Pellentesque suscipit suscipit aliquet. Nulla et pharetra tellus, nec semper erat. Praesent metus mauris, accumsan ut tempus ut, dignissim eget ante. Nulla eget diam sit amet enim luctus interdum. Quisque volutpat, enim vitae sollicitudin fermentum, odio metus fermentum ante, nec ultrices augue dolor eu eros. Nam eu venenatis dui. Vivamus volutpat accumsan nibh, in tincidunt lorem commodo sit amet.

Ut rhoncus, nunc ut lacinia vulputate, nisi purus efficitur massa, id suscipit ex felis nec mauris. Cras malesuada sapien et congue consectetur. Mauris molestie nisl vel purus convallis rutrum. Sed tristique dictum consectetur. Curabitur justo ante, semper sit amet ultrices at, placerat at lacus. Aenean lorem quam, tempor nec arcu nec, viverra ornare mi. Aenean ante velit, vestibulum non libero a, ullamcorper vulputate lectus. Aenean congue, metus ac lobortis dignissim, elit nunc interdum magna, eu sagittis neque mi vitae nibh. Etiam eget lacus quam. Duis quis augue eget eros congue molestie eget at dui.

<footer>Copyright &copy; 2017 LeagueOn. all rights reserved</footer>
```