# Fix footer to bottom - even if the body don't have content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to know how to stick the footer to the bottom, even if the page doesn't have content. I searched solutions before making this post, but no real solutions.
The newbie solution could be to put margin-top but that could make a full page look ugly. Btw, thanks in advance and that's my code.

```
<footer class"footer">
    //content
</footer>

.footer {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: see this: [fix-footer-to-bottom-of-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915550/fix-footer-to-bottom-of-page)

Answer (score 0):

If your page has no content,
you can fix the footer to the bottom of the screen.

```
<footer class"footer">
    //content
</footer>


.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1La17zsr/

Comment: Thanks! But there is a problem, if the page hasn't content, it's ok, the footer is fixed to the bottom. But when the page is full, the footer is about 250px from the top.