# How i make a shown footer at bottom page on laravel?

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5, footer

I make a footer. but to see the footer, i need to scroll it down. I want too see the footer without scrolling the page

Comment: your question is not clear, please explain it clearly so that we can help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix footer to bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915550/fix-footer-to-bottom-of-page)

Answer (score 3):

Just look for the css-class of your footer and add

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

to this class in one of your style sheets.

You can also directly add this in your HTML / blade-template by adding the attribute `style="position:fixed;bottom:0"` to the outmost container of your footer.