# Footer won't stay at bottom in Firefox

Tags: css, vue.js, firefox, position

So I keep my footer at the bottom of my page with the following code:

It's a vue project so #app is my container with my content and footer in.

```
#app {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
}
```

This works great in Chrome but somehow Firefox doesn't really care and just let's my footer float below my content.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix footer to bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915550/fix-footer-to-bottom-of-page)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be changing position to position: fixed.