# Get the footer to stick to the bottom without adding white space to the page (min-height: 100vh)

Tags: css, height, whitespace, footer

On some of the pages of the website I am creating, due to lack of content, the footer does not stick to the bottom and there's an unwanted white space below it.
Googling the issue, I've found different solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443606/make-footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page-correctly). So I figured `min-height: 100vh` is the ultimate solution. The problem is when I use that property for the main page container, it adds white space below the content to get the footer stick to the bottom which is again undesirable:

It seems to me that it just place the white space elsewhere (in the middle of the page instead of at the bottom of the page). Is there a neater solution for keeping the footer at the bottom?

Comment: Can't you use position : fixed ?

Comment: Thats a duplicate btw see :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915550/fix-footer-to-bottom-of-page

Comment: can you upload your image again?

Comment: @M.RMRF: Why? I just wanted to show what undesirable white spaces I am referring to.

Comment: images you uploaded are not available...

Comment: @M.RMRF: Oops, I'll update it with real images!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to following to your footer...

```
#bottom-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks